How can I filter the options in a Select in a dynamic AntD form?
Problem Description
I am working with a dynamic form using Ant Design (Antd) in a React project. The form includes a Select component that dynamically renders options based on an array of fields, each with an id and name. The form was functioning correctly until I added a filter to exclude already selected fields from the dropdown options.
Issue: After applying the filter, when I select an option from the filtered list, the Select component displays the value (the id of the field) instead of the label (the name of the field).
Code Example
Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nditzv?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FDynamicForm.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx
Additional Information
"antd": "^5.19.4"
react": "^18.3.1"

Expected Behavior
The Select component should display the name of the field after selection.
Actual Behavior
The Select component displays the id of the field after selection.

I checked the code example and run it. The issue you were facing didn't actually happen. But I noticed that you are not creating the fieldOptions correctly. It should only have value and label keys. It may be causing the wrong behavior. Try doing this
  const fieldOptions = filteredFields.map(({ id, name }) => ({
    value: id,
    label: name,
  }));

instead of this
  const fieldOptions = filteredFields.map(({ id, name }) => ({
    value: id,
    label: <span>{name}</span>,
    name,
  }));

